# How I can get current active users from Firebase with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an application using flutter and firebase. I need to get active users from firebase.
I am trying by creating a boolean field in firebase collection with name **isActive = false** and initiate a function with name **_checkInternetConnectivity();** in this function I set when the internet connection is available update value of **isActive = true** in firebase and when there is no internet connection update value **isActive = false** so far my code is working perfectly but problem is that when internet connection is available it set the value of **isActive = true** but when there is no internet connection it unable to update the value **isActive = false**.

code is here:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkInternetConnectivity();
}

_checkInternetConnectivity() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Profile').doc(user.uid).update({
        'isActive': true,
      });
      print('done mobile');
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      _addData.doc(user.uid).update({
        'isActive': true,
      });
      print('done wifi');
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Profile').doc(user.uid).update({
        'isActive': false,
      });
      print('done none');
    }
  }
}
```

so, how I can improve this code or any other way by which I can get active users from firebase with flutter.
 Regards

Answer (score 1):

**OnDisconnect**

The OnDisconnect class is used to manage operations that will be run on the server when this client disconnects. It can be used to add or remove data based on a client's connection status. It is very useful in applications looking for 'presence' functionality.

Instances of this class are obtained by calling onDisconnect on a Firebase Database ref.

### Your solution is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/OnDisconnect)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a field like `lastActiveTimestamp` and update it every time an user opens the app. Then you can filter users by the last time they use the app.